# Github git pull asking for credentials. Trying to use the personal access token it keeps bugging me about, can't figure out how

Tags: linux, git, github, ssh, https

I have a bot hosted on another computer. I have cloned the repo onto the second computer and whenever I want to update the files in it, I do a `git pull`.
At this point, it asks for my credentials (username and password).

However, recently Github has been sending me emails saying that this method is becoming deprecated and tells me to use a personal access token instead.

I've generated one but can't figure out where to put it or how to use it.
It seems to work in place of my password, but is there a way to make it stop asking for my credentials?

Comment: I don't think that the token method will allow you to avoid prompts.  My understanding is that the only way to **not** get prompted for credentials would be to switch to `ssh` rather than `https` and use a public key-pair instead of credentials.

Comment: Git itself never does any authentication. It passes that job off on to some other program. The other program, a *credential helper* as Git calls it, is OS-specific. You mention linux in a tag, so you want the Linux credential helpers here. The standard ones are `credential-cache` and `credential-store`. See also [the `gitcredentials` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems to work in place of my password, but is there a way to make it stop asking for my credentials?

If you are using the latest Git, you can use:

```
git config --global credential.helper manager-core
printf "protocol=https\nhost=github.com\nusername=<me>\npassword=<my_token>" |\
  git-credential-manager-core store
```

Then, Git won't ask for your credentials anymore.

On Linux/Mac, you might have to install [GCM (Git-Credential-Manager-Core)](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core) first.
On Linux, add:

```
sudo apt-get install libsecret-1-0
git config --global credential.credentialStore secretservice
```

Comment: Using `secretservice` together with `git-credential-manager-core` as the helper, it still bothers me once a day for my access token. Any ideas?

Comment: @Slbox What version of Git and GCM are you using? On which Linux OS version? What does `git config --global credential.helper` return?

Comment: Very appreciative for your reply. It's Kubuntu 21.10 and the `credential.helper` returns `/usr/local/share/gcm-core/git-credential-manager-core`

Comment: @Slbox What do `git version` and `git credential-manager-core --version` return?

Comment: Thanks again for your reply @VonC. git is at `2.32.0` and credential manager core is at `2.0.696+4365b917da`

Comment: @Slbox Looks good. In your repository folder, what does `git remote -v` return? Does it start with an `https://github.com/...` or a `git@github.com:...`?

Comment: The result begins with `https://github.com/...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245830/discussion-between-vonc-and-slbox).